# How to automatically open cmd as admin

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I'm creating a program for my school project, and it is making calls to some batch files.

Some of the commands will not execute except with admin privileges. How do I resolve this please? Any solution in VBS, VB or batch code will be appreciated, as I'm coding in Visual Basic.

Comment: Have you tried running your script as admin?

Comment: You can run your initiating script/executable as admin, and that will carry through for the rest of the processes that spawn off of your program and any others from those children.

Comment: You can create a shortcut for `cmd` on desktop then right click on it and select **Properties/Advance** and select the `Run as admin` option.

Comment: take a look at elevate.vbs and the [Elevation PowerToys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/elevationpowertoys/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this batch code:

```
runas /user:ADMINUSERNAME BATCHFILE.BAT
```

`ADMINUSERNAME` is the administrator account for your computer, and `BATCHFILE.BAT` is the path to your batch file.

Comment: AFAIK runas does not elevate see also [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/332363/57579)